# How to use system custom fonts in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, fonts, android-studio-3.5

In some devices, there is a option to customize the font in the device settings. Also, some devices may not use the `Roboto` font. How can I ensure that my app can use the system font, instead of a fixed font in my app? I am using Kotlin 1.3 on Android Studio 3.5.

Comment: don't use custom fonts in any of your views or style and you'r good to go.

Comment: Thanks. "don't use custom fonts" means use the default ```sans-serif``` in Android Studio, right?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use custom fonts in your views like -

```
<TextView
    ....
    android:fontFamily="@fonts/Arial"
    ....
 />
```

or by `TypeFace` or by style like -

```
<style name="Regular">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/dancing_script</item>
 </style>
```

If you set a custom font manually than your app will use that custom font in every device.
But if you don't use a custom font than device's font is applied on your views.